# Связь many-to-many для трех моделей

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Есть три модели -  школа, учителя и ученики.

```
public class Pupil
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FavouriteLesson { get; set; }

    public SchoolEntity School { get; set; }
    public List<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }

    public IList<DataLink> DataLink { get; set; }
}

public class SchoolEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool DeepEnglishLearning { get; set; }
    public int? SchoolRating { get; set; }

    public List<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
    public List<Pupil> Pupils { get; set; }

    public IList<DataLink> DataLink { get; set; }
}

public class Teacher
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    public SchoolEntity School { get; set; }
    public List<Pupil> Pupils { get; set; }

    public IList<DataLink> DataLink { get; set; }
}
```

И есть класс DataLinks для создания связи многие ко многим:

- у школы может быть много учеников и учителей
- у учеников может быть одна школа и много учителей
- у учителей может быть одна школа и много учеников.

**DataLink.cs**

```
public class DataLink
{
   public int TeacherId { get; set; }
   public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }

   public int PupilId { get; set; }
   public Pupil Pupil { get; set; }
}
```

Не пойму, я в DatabaseContext  правильно прописал modelBuilder?

**DatabaseContext**

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {}

    public DbSet<SchoolEntity> SchoolTable { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Teacher> TeacherTable { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Pupil> PupilTable { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DataLink> DataLink { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<SchoolEntity>().ToTable("School");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Teacher>().ToTable("Teacher");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Pupil>().ToTable("Pupil");

        // Это написано правильно?
        modelBuilder.Entity<DataLink>()
            .HasOne(dl => dl.Teacher)
            .WithMany(dl => dl.DataLink)
            .IsRequired()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        modelBuilder.Entity<DataLink>()
            .HasOne(dl => dl.Pupil)
            .WithMany(dl => dl.DataLink)
            .IsRequired()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
}
```

Comment: EF Core? Или 6.X?

Comment: @АндрейNOP EF Core

Comment: Вам в DataLink не нужна ссылка на School. Вам нужна одна промежуточная таблица для связи M:N между Pupil и Teacher, больше в ней ничего не должно быть

Comment: @АндрейNOP Спасибо, обновил вопрос. Убрал School из DataLink и  DatabaseContext. Так должно быть?